# Print all lines after every single blank line in Shell

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I am trying to print all the lines after every blank line in a file. Can anyone suggest a command in shell?

Sample File :

```
line1                                                                        
line2

line 3                                                                        
line 4

line 5
line 7

line 6
```

Output expected :

> line 3
> line 4
> line 5
> line 7
> line 6

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: `after every blank line` `line 4` is not (right) after a blank line.

Comment: IMHO shouldn't output be `line2` and `line4` only? Kindly confirm once on same.

Comment: I have edited the sample output. The requirement is to print all lines after each blank line. So the samples are to the point. Also, I am posting my effort.

Comment: How is that different than deleting all lines prior to the fist blank line, and removing all blank lines?

Comment: In your sample input, the 6th line (which is empty) appears after the blank line on line 3.  According to the description "print all lines after each blank line", line 6 (the blank line) should be printed.  You need to properly specify your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, written and tested in GNU `awk` in shown samples only.

```
awk '/^$/{found=1;next} found && !/^$/' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 7
line 6
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above solution.

```
awk '             ##Starting awk program from here.
/^$/{             ##Checking if a line is an empty line then do following.
  found=1         ##Setting found to 1 here.
  next            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found && !/^$/    ##Checking condition if found is SET and line is NOT empty then print that line.
' Input_file      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/\S/b;:a;n;//p;ba' file
```

Turn off implicit printing by using `-n` option.

Throw away all lines until the first empty one, then only print non-empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

Another sed:

```sh
sed -n '/^$/,${/./p}' infile
```

For the address range `/^$/,$` (first empty line until last line), print non-empty lines (`/./p`).

For macOS sed, use `{/./p;}` (extra semicolon).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a very simple `awk` with an empty `RS` that breaks down input by each blank line:

```
awk -v RS= 'NR>1' file
```

```
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 7
line 6
```